# Does SHA-512 become suitable to store a password if we use salting and iteration with it?

Tags: hash, sha

Today I have read [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/96428/which-hashing-algorithm-is-better-to-use-to-store-a-password-sha256-or-sha512) discussion about SHA-256 and SHA-512 and that we should not use any of them to store a password securely. And I have read [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846)  that instead we can use the PBKDF2 hashing function, because we can use salt and specify the number of iterations. That is great, but what about if I use a salt and iterating with SHA-512?
For example, consider this simple implementation:

```
string Password= "admin";
for(int I= 0; I<numberOfIterations, I++)
{
   Password = sha512(Password+salt);
}
store(Password);
```

So is it possible to apply something like this?

Comment: PBKDF2 is not the same as sha2 + salt + iterations. This explanation is just used to simplify the algorithm and make it more understandable for a wider audience.

Comment: i would suggest doing more reading first. There is a lot of literature on this.

Comment: @JerrySaravia could you guide me to an article talking about this topic `using salt and iterating with sha512`

Comment: I would suggest for some basics: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

One thing it mentions is : `Key stretching is implemented using a special type of CPU-intensive hash function. Don't try to invent your own–simply iteratively hashing the hash of the password isn't enough as it can be parallelized in hardware and executed as fast as a normal hash. Use a standard algorithm like PBKDF2 or bcrypt. You can find a PHP implementation of PBKDF2 here.'

Comment: Is there a reason that you are looking to roll your own password storage mechanism?

Comment: Why down-vote instead of answering "No, because rolling your own is always a bad idea"?

Comment: I suggest bcrypt over PBKDF2.  Don't use SHA-512, it's a big mistake.

Comment: @SakamakiIzayoi I know hat it is a big mistake to use it alone but I need a convincing answer about why should not I use it when I use salting and iteration with it.
[read here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247741/iterate-sha512-to-make-it-more-secure)

Comment: @user3260672 There are already plenty of posts on here that explain why bcrypt is better than other hashing algos such as MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256, SHA-512, etc.

Comment: I have read a lot of them and they talk about the sha family when you do not use them with salting and iteration

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Today I have read this discussion about **wheels** and that we should not **simply strap ourselves to a wheel** to **travel on a multilane highway**. And I have read here that instead we can **take the bus**, because **it has safety features**. That is great, but what about if I use **a seatbelt** with **my wheel**?

Salting is good. Iterations are good. SHA-512 is a good general-purpose hashing algorithm. But you can't just take a bunch of good things and strap them together and expect to have something safe to use. Like a commercial bus, PBKDF2 (or bcrypt, or scrypt, or [Argon2](https://password-hashing.net/candidates.html)) has lots of advantages over a homemade solution, primarily:

1. It has been tested extensively by experts.
2. There are multiple implementations, so your user database can be copied to a new platform with minimal fuss.
3. It has protections against problems you don't know are even problems (i.e. it was built by experts).